# Facing problem with submersible pump (5V)

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, dc-motor

I am using a submersible pump (5V) with a power supply 12 volt 1 amps adapter. I know that its operational voltage is 3.3-6 volt that's why I am using IC7805 regulator ic in my circuit. I am facing a problem is that after some time my pump starts to make noisy sound and then stop. I also try to run a pump using 5 volts 2 amps mobile charger but the same issue occurs. I already lost my 10+ pump so can you suggest a circuit with a 12-volt power supply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the part number of your pump. These pumps will easily die if run dry or for various other reasons. Use a multimeter to verify that you're giving it not more than 6 volts. If that's the case than it's the pump, not the power supply that is the issue.

Comment: Yes i check with multimeter voltage is 5 and i use single pump with 12 volt 1 amps power adapter.

Comment: First thought was that the 7805 is going to overheat, hit thermal limit, and cycle on and off there for a while, turning the pump on and off, perhaps explaining the noise. But you say it also happens with a 5V 2A charger - perhaps post specs of the pump, it may be drawing current unevenly e.g. And perhaps the pump is overheating for a reason unrelated to the power supply - blockage that takes a while to show, e.g. or air in the tube

Comment: First check if the pump is rated for continuous use. Many are not. Also, make sure any particles are filtered out before reaching the pump, they can easily block, stall, overheat and die (or kill your power supply). Reliable and silent pumps are expensive, unfortunately.